# log4net RollingFileAppender: How to zero-pad the iteration number of filenames

Tags: log4net-configuration, zero-pad

I have a C# application that uses log4net for logging facilities. Using the RollingFileAppender and a mostly-default configuration, I get a list of files that either is or isn't convenient, depending on whether or not the program I'm using to view does smart ordering:

```
trace.log.xml
trace.log.xml.1
trace.log.xml.10
...
trace.log.xml.19
trace.log.xml.2
trace.log.xml.20
...
trace.log.xml.2015-11-16.19
trace.log.xml.2015-11-16.2
trace.log.xml.2015-11-16.20
trace.log.xml.2015-11-16.3
...
trace.log.xml.2015-11-16.9
trace.log.xml.3
trace.log.xml.4
trace.log.xml.5
trace.log.xml.6
trace.log.xml.7
trace.log.xml.8
trace.log.xml.9
```

I'd like to remedy this with some zero-padding. Instead of e.g. `trace.log.xml.5` or `trace.log.xml.17`, I'd rather have the filename be `trace.log.xml.0005` or `trace.log.xml.0017`.

(I have a `%04d` in hand and I don't know where it goes.)